# How to get a character from another character in java

Tags: java

Suppose the unicode of A is \u9876. I want to get 7 characters after A. ie H.
is there some way to get do (A's unicode ) + 7 and then cast it to a char.

Comment: Sure, just add 7 to the `char` value.

Comment: Why can't you just add 7 to the `char`?  You don't need to convert it to unicode.

Comment: Remember, a `char` is a numerical type.

Comment: Yeah, and `"Number"` is a `String`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This post is not an answer but a "confusion cleanup" post.

First of all, a Unicode code point ranges from U+0000 to U+10FFFF; in all this range, some code points are in fact invalid.

Java's `char` is, in essence, a UTF-16 code unit. For Unicode code points outside the Basic Multilingual plane, that is, above U+FFFF, two chars are needed to encode one code point; see [`Character.toChars()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toChars-int-). For code points inside the BMP there is a one-to-one mapping between Unicode and `char`.

Other than that, despite its particular role, a `char` is a numeric type; it is also the only unsigned numeric type in Java. You can use arithmetic operations on it, and for a code point inside the BMP, adding 7 to a `char` which is '\u9876' will give code point '\u9883'.

But given the above, this is a dangerous manoeuver...

(fwiw, above the BMP, `Character.toChars()` will return a "pair of char"s; the first element of the returned array will be a lead surrogate and the second will be a trail surrogate; the Java API still uses the old Unicode terminology and calls them a "high" and "low" surrogate respectively. For more details see the [Wikipedia article on UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), which does a pretty good job at explaining what is what)

Comment: "This post is not an answer" .. well it sure does look like one :P

Comment: This sounds like a convoluted way to say, "You can't add things together, they might overflow!"  Isn't 9883 well under FFFF?  You can add chars.  There are just some dusty corners of java that have to be understood to do it.

Comment: @CandiedOrange if it were that simple... No, the main problem is not overflow; the main problem is that you can create an "invalid" `char` and, in fact, and invalid char sequence -- an entire `String` which consists of no valid code points at all. Arithmetic overflow is the least of your problem here.

Comment: You would only create an invalid char by incrementing beyond the valid range.  Stay away from reserved bits and everything should be fine.  I know different encoding schemes reserve different bits and use multiple and variable bytes to encode a character but don't make it sound like he can't print an ASCII table with out typing each out by hand.

Comment: @CandiedOrange did I ever say that? It seems you have misunderstood what I wanted to say completely. And when you talk Java, talking ASCII is a fundamental mistake. It just happens that Unicode's U+0000 to U+007f match ASCII, but the similarity ends here.

Comment: @fge Incrementing into an invalid value is overflowing.  It means you touched bits that were not yours.  What bits are yours depends on the encoding and which byte you happen to be twiddling.  Unless you're saying that happens in this example this is still not an answer.  Oh and the match with ASCII was by design not happenstance.  Why can't I use java to print an ASCII table?  I've done it before.

Comment: @CandiedOrange you don't understand, do you? "Incrementing into an invalid value is overflowing." <-- not with `char`. If you increment a `char` value and happen to yield a lead surrogate, it is _still_ a valid `char`; but this `char` as a String is an invalid Unicode sequence.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54419/discussion-between-candiedorange-and-fge).

Answer (score 1):

Well you have given the answer. Just add the seven to the char value and java will know what to do for it.

Comment: You might think it's that simple but try it first and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't integer promotion fun?  It's so nice to think you have one thing when you really have another.

See if this helps you do what you want to do:

```
char test = '\u0041'; 
char add = 7;
char sum1 = '\u0041' + 7;      //Works
//char sum2 = '\u0041' + add;  //Type mismatch, cannot convert from int to char
//char sum3 = test + 7;        //Type mismatch, cannot convert from int to char
//char sum2 = test + (char)7;  //Type mismatch, cannot convert from int to char
//char sum4 = (int) test + 7;  //Type mismatch, cannot convert from int to char
char sum5 = (char) ( (int)test + 7 );//Works
char sum6 = (char) ( test + add );   //Works
//char sum7 = test + add;      //Type mismatch, cannot convert from int to char

System.out.println("test = " + test);
System.out.println("sum1 = " + sum1);
System.out.println("sum5 = " + sum5);
System.out.println("sum6 = " + sum6);
```

Why? Integer promotion.  Java only treats char's as chars in memory.  In the CPU they become integers.  Most of the time this happens invisibly and you don't notice it.  I think this time you did.  In short, you forgot to cast your char back to a char.  Fun fun stuff.

Also, the code for A is \u0041

9876 is this little guy: 顶
http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=9876

and 9883 is this little guy: 颃
http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=9883